# What does Dumbledore's sign-off translate to?

Tags: harry-potter, fantastic-beasts, translation

In the *Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them* book the foreword is written by Dumbledore.

In the last he says

> To wizards, I say merely: Draco dormiens nunquam titillandus.

Now Dumbledore is known for saying gibberish prior to the school feasts,  however this seems to be Latin or pseudo Latin.

**What does the line mean in English?**

Comment: A dragon in your home is 94 times as amusing. Draco = dragon, dormien = home, nun- 9, quad - 4, titillandus - tittilating.

Comment: @Broklynite that is really stretching there, dormien is sleep (dormitory, dormant), where a house is domus (domicile, domestic).  94 would be nonaginta quattuor, as nine is novem(I'd go on and say November, but we've stopped using that as the ninth month for a while), and quattuor is four.  Though you are kind of close with the last word.

Comment: @CBredlow https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/joke

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It translates from Latin to English :

> Never Tickle a Sleeping Dragon

Which is the motto of **Hogwarts School of Witchcraft and Wizardry** <sup>[1](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Hogwarts_School_of_Witchcraft_and_Wizardry)</sup>

[This post](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10658/whats-the-point-of-the-hogwarts-motto) discusses the motto and possible meanings and origins.

Answer (score 10):

Never tickle the sleeping dragon.

- Draco: Dragon http://www.dictionary.com/browse/draco
- Dormiens: Sleeping https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dormiens
- Nunquam: Never https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/numquam#Latin
- Titallandus: Tickle https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/titillo#Latin